# d3: dragging for static off-screen visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm generating a d3 force layout from data which is potentially very large.  My goal is to draw some of the layout off screen and allow the user to access the unseen portions with a click-and-drag.  Crucially, I want the layout to be static, so clicking and dragging a node moves the whole layout rather than just the individual node.

In other words, I want the behavior of [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/0389e39fad95e1cf29ce) but without the node dragging.  [This simpler example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) also seems relevant.  But so far all of my attempts at modifying these examples have broken them in various interesting ways.  Also, I'm not interested in zooming (for now).  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the drag on the nodes remove the drag events from the node

```
node.data(graph.nodes).enter().append("circle") ...
//remove this drag part so that the dragging of circle don't happen
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
              .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
              .on("drag", dragged)
              .on("dragend", dragended));
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xqf03h17/1/)

Hope this helps!